# Can't print out to log cat

Tags: java, android, logcat

I was able to print out to the log cat for debugging yesterday, but for some reason it will not show up today.

I am trying to get the id of an image button.

In my onClickListener for the button:

```
clicker = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageButton clicked = (ImageButton) v;
        makeMove(clicked.getId());

        System.out.print("ID is:"+clicked.getId());
    }
};
```

Would there be any reason why it would not show up on LogCat? I tried to set a filter to just SystemOut but got nothing.

Have you got any tips on getting it to output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print into `LogCat`, replace `System.out.print()` method with `Log.i()`, `Log.d()` or `Log.w()` method as like below...

```
System.out.print("ID is:"+clicked.getId());
```

with

```
Log.i("ID is:", " "+clicked.getId());
```

Because, `System.out.print()` is designed to print in the `Console` and `Log.i()` is designed to print in the `LogCat`.

So, to print in the `LogCat`, you should use `Log` class and its methods. The `Log` class's methods maintain some `TAG` as their first argument which helps to sort-out printed log in the `LogCat`.

Comment: Thanks I should of researched further. Although, how come 'System.out' it worked yesterday but not today? Could there be problems with eclipse or, what could i possibly be, considering I did not touch my code since yesterday?

Comment: @CodeError ...the question, you are referring to, is already closed. What do you mean by "Take a look"?

Comment: @HamidShatu Sir : The user delete this page .Sorry :o

Answer (score 0):

Why you aren't using the

```
Log.d(TAG, stirng)
```

instead of

```
System.out.print()?
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use `Log.i()` in order to print logs in Android.

```
Log.i("ID is: ", "" + clicked.getId());
```